# Is it possible to setup 2 different AIRFLOW_HOME path on the same server in bash_profile

Tags: bash, airflow

I need to setup these two paths in my bash_profile
export AIRFLOW_HOME=`pwd`/airflow
and
export AIRFLOW_HOME=`pwd`/airflow_2
for the same server so that two different versions of airflow can coexist. Is this possible?

Can't think of any solution.. any suggestions will of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Every environment variable must, **by definition**, *be unique and non-ambiguous*.

Either the software itself, *or the script wrapping the software*, could work with another environment variable (i.e. AIRFLOW_HOME_OPTS) which could be assigned the following value

```
AIRFLOW_HOME_OPTS="pwd/airflow:pwd/airflow_2"
```

which the wrapper could then parse depending on **command line options**, i.e. --default/--v2 .

Assuming this is an installation dedicated to a single user, you could also have the libraries installed in each of

```
pwd/airflow_1
pwd/airflow_2
```

and, again via wrapper option, create a symlink on the fly to whichever is the one you wish to use at the time the command executes, and removes that when the program ends.